# Nodejs seemingly installed properly, but getting error 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Nodejs is installed properly, but getting error 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Things I've tried:

`node -v` works fines in bash terminal, v18.16.0 is installed

checked that node exists in PATH variable: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`

uninstalled and reinstalled node

Everything seems OK until I run node dependend commands like npm install or npm start, giving me either 'node' or 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command errors.

I've fiddled around with some of the solutions, but I just end up with different errors. One of them is especially weird: ('"node"' is not recognized...) which is strange, since the node is in an extra pair of "".

Are there any other fixes I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed (Sort of): Stopped using bash and switched over to using VSCode terminal: tried running npm install, 'react-script' is not recognized -> ran npm install react-scripts -> npm start now works.